# Trouble splitting each line in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having touble splitting lines in a text file

The code

```
import numpy as np

# Data and labels
pred_X = []
pred_Y = []
X = []
Y = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fp:
    fd = fp.read()
    for line in fd[:40]:
        line = line.split()
        X.append(line)
    for line in fd[-40:]:
        line = line.split()
        pred_X.append(line)

print(X)
```

The text file entry

```
5000    1.032   R   2.54    B   0.270   0.329   0.132   6   3047    1354    2455    R   2.54    L   0.298   0.386   0.231   1   3400
```

The result:

```
[['5'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['1'], ['.'], ['0'], ['3'], ['2']... ['3'],['4'], ['0'], ['0']]
```

Strangely this works:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.split()
        print(line)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: It shouldn't be strange.  In the first `fd` is a string, which may include newline characters but they're not treated any differently.  So `fd[:40]` is saying the first 40 characters, irrespective of any concept of lines.  And then you're looping over a string, so each `line` in the first example will be an individual character.  In the second example, `for line in fp` ***is*** respecting the concept of lines, and will enter your `for` loop for each, and `line` will be a newline-terminated string.

Comment: @jedwards But shouldn't `fd[:40]` be the first 40 lines?

Comment: No.  `fp.read()` returns the entire file, newlines included, as a single string, so `fd` is a string.  Slicing a string as you do with `fd[:40]` will also return a string -- the first 40 *characters* of the file.  If you want the concept of lines you really should use an approach like the second, or, something like [`fd.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) or [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

Comment: I see, I just changed my code to `fd.readlines` and it's working, thank you!